# How to select multiple items with multiple quantities in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Models.py

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MealMenu(BaseModel):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True
    )
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item_name} {self.price}"


class MealOrder(BaseModel):

    RECEIVED = "Received"
    PENDING = "Pending"
    REJECTED = "Rejected"

    MEAL_CHOICES = (
        ("Breakfast", "Breakfast"),
        ("Lunch", "Lunch"),
        ("Dinner", "Dinner"),
    )
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (RECEIVED, "Received"),
        (PENDING, "Pending"),
        (REJECTED, "Rejected"),
    )

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, null=False)
    total_items = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    total_amounts = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(MealMenu, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=False)
    meal_time = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=MEAL_CHOICES)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
```

I have two models. In First Model i have created a menu item_name,price and quantity.
In MealOrder i have foreign key MealMenu Model and created quantity field separately.
I want to select multiple items with their multiple quantities. But i can't understand the scenario.

Comment: You'd better make some examples.

Answer (score 1):

So you could have a separate model to handle the quantity for different items in an order. 
Like this:

```
class MealOrderItem(BaseModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        MealOrder, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    meal = ForeignKey(
        MealMenu, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

This will help you create multiple meal menu selections for an order with each having its own quantity.